# Converting source blob Android kernel back to Git repository

Tags: android, git, linux-kernel, android-kernel

Hope this is the right place to ask, and not softwareengineering.stackexchange.

A couple of enterprising people released a CM11 build for my ancient (Samsung Galaxy S DUOS, released 2012) Android device some time ago.  I successfully rebuilt it against the LineageOS 11 code, and now I am wondering about updating it to something newer.  It is probably not the best place to start, since newer Androids can use older kernels, but I am looking at the kernel.  Basically the kernel in the sources is a source blob based on 3.0 (presumably what Samsung supplied) in a Git repository with a hundred or so commits on top. Using git log -S and internet search I can see that a lot of the difference against android-3.0 is back-ported patches.  So the question is how best to convert the blob into a normal Git repository.

My first idea is to locate the appropriate changes in the kernel.org/Android/CodeAurora git trees and cherry pick or git-am them into an android-3.0 tree until I have reduced the difference to something manageable, then to apply the rest as a final commit, and after that to try rebasing to a later (android-3.3 for a start) kernel version.  I am sure though that someone out there will be able to suggest ways to improve on that (maybe Git has some clever tricks that I am not aware of).

Comment: You need a root access in order to do that

Comment: You may want to phrase your question differently.  Talking about "wanting to update the kernel" makes us think this is a question about use of an android device, which is off topic.  You need to carefully read your question to figure out you're really asking for how to do something with git.  That should be the title, and all the stuff about Android is immaterial

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Yes, my device is running an Android version I built myself, so that is not a problem.

Comment: @GabeSechan I adjusted the title - does that look better?

Comment: Well, no answers so far, so I have started out with the way I outlined in the question.  Looks like it will be a long process in my short free time, but on the bright side it is still more interesting than many similar tasks I have done, and it seems at this very early stage to be working reasonably well.  I will write up an answer to my question if I get anywhere.